# Using Dominated Convergence Theorem to interchange Integral and Taylor Series of Sine

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Sigma_n a_n(xt)^n$ be the standard Taylor series expansion of $sin(xt)$.  I want to show that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\Sigma_n a_n(xt)^n}{e^t-1}dt=\Sigma_n\int_0^{\infty}\frac{a_n(xt)^n}{e^t-1}dt$.  I think the dominated convergence theorem will do the trick, by making $|\Sigma_{n=1}^k a_n(xt)^n|$ dominated by some integrable function $g$ for all $k$.  But what dominator do I use?

The obvious choice of dominator is $\frac{1}{e^t-1}$, but $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{e^t-1}$ does not converge.  So what other dominator can I use?

Comment: The dominator can be $\frac{1}{e^t-1}\sum_n|a_n(xt)^n|$ ($=\frac{\sinh|x|t}{e^t-1}$). Of course, this is valid only for $|x|<1$ (otherwise the interchange is indeed illegal).

Comment: How do I show that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh|x|t}{e^t-1}dt$ is finite?

Comment: For $|x|<1$ (don't forget it) this is easy - the integrand is _exponentially decaying_, with a _removable singularity_ at $t=0$.

Comment: I don't have much intuition for the hyperbolic sine function, so this isn't obvious to me.  Can you post an answer elaborating on this?

Comment: Yeah, so the integrand is some function with exponential functions in the numerator and denominator.  It's not immediately obvious to me that it's integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are interested in is whether the integral converges, I think we can argue as follows to say that it does: Since $\frac{\sin xt}{e^{t}-1}\to x$ as $t\to 0^+$ is suffices to consider $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xt}{e^{t}-1}dt,$ in which case we have

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin xt}{e^{t}-1}dt\le \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin xt|}{(t+\frac{t^{2}}{2}+\frac{t^{3}}{6}+O(t^{4}))}dt=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin xt|}{t(1+\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^{2}}{6}+O(t^{3}))}dt\le \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^{2}}{6}}\le 6\int^{\infty}_1\frac{dt}{t^{2}}$